# Can CNN recognition answer "Not any one of these classes"

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I use CNN to do image recognition for twenty classes of images.
I also want CNN to tell me when the image is not belong to any one of these twenty classes.
Softmax can only give me the answer of one of these twenty classes.
Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, there are ways, but it is not a programming prioblem this should be asked in the AI or Data Science SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a "negative class" of random objects that are not your 20 classes. Training on negative data should increase accuracy and generalization because it can help the network figure out the object from a background